# Checking ExtensionAttributes

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I had a list of 50 users with the Active Directory `extensionAttribute12` sent to me, I was told that `extensionAttribute13` was mixed up. So far, as I go through and check in AD, I don't see this to be so.

I would like to use PowerShell to check the list he gave me and export to my own list without going one by one.

I have this and when I runs it seems to export all users, but in my list, I only have 1 user. Later, I would like to run on the list of 50. I don't understand why I get all of the users.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$UserList=Import-Csv C:\Users\RHyman\Documents\ExListTest.csv
FOREACH ($Person in $UserList) 
{
    Import-Csv C:\Users\rhyman\Documents\ExListTest.csv | ForEach {
    Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties UserPrincipalName, extensionAttribute12, emailAddress, SAMAccountName | `
        Select UserPrincipalName, extensionAttribute12, extensionAttribute13 | `
        Export-CSV c:\allinfo.csv -NoTypeInformation
    }
}
```

I've done some editing, this is what I have now:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$UserList=Import-Csv C:\Users\RHyman\Documents\ExListTest.csv
FOREACH ($Person in $UserList) 
{
  
    Get-ADUser -Identity "$UserList" -Properties UserPrincipalName, extensionAttribute12, emailAddress, SAMAccountName | 
    Select UserPrincipalName, extensionAttribute12, extensionAttribute13 | 
    Export-CSV C:\Users\RHyman\Documents\allinfo.csv -NoTypeInformation
    
}
```

What I'm most concerned with is that the `Get-Aduser` has error:

> Cannot find an object with identity: '@{UserPrincipalName=first.last@x.x.gov

It sees the name on the list but I may have to go to the csv file and change the way the list displays the names.

Revised script: Only thing now exported csv is empty

Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$UserList=Import-Csv C:\Users\RHyman\Documents\ExListTest.csv
FOREACH ($Person in $UserList)
{

```
Get-ADUser  -Filter {(mail -eq "$UserList")} -Properties 
UserPrincipalName, extensionAttribute12, emailAddress, SAMAccountName | 
Select UserPrincipalName, extensionAttribute12, extensionAttribute13 | 
Export-CSV C:\Users\RHyman\Documents\allinfo.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

}

Finally got what I was looking for and it does what I wanted
This is what I needed and used Get-Content
Get-ADUser -Filter {mail -like $_}

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: You use `Get-ADUser -Filter *` and you don't understand why you get all users?

Comment: ...also, what does the extension attribute even have to do with your question in the first place? Seems to me your question is not about extension attributes at all.

Comment: [1] Does that CSV contain a column for the user to fetch with `Get-ADUser` (now you are asking it to get **all** users). [2] Why are you repeating the `Import-Csv` cmdlet of the same csv file over-and-over again inside the foreach loop?. Please open that CSV file in notepad, copy the first 3 or 4 lines and add that to your question as formatted text. Of course, **sanitize** any sensitive information

Comment: I removed, some of the lines, trying to figure out how to work with the get-aduser, if I open up PS and type Get-ADuser  username I get results, but if I type in Get-ADuser user.name@place.gov it says cannot find and object with identity...... if this is how the list is presented  I guess I need something else that will return this type of search

Comment: In your updated code, you're looping through the list, but then feeding the entire list to `Get-ADUser` in every iteration of the loop. I think you want `Get-ADUser -Identity $Person ...`

Comment: What columns does your CSV have?

Answer (score 0):

You are passing entire csv [Get-ADUser -Identity "$UserList"] into Identity use below instead.

$UserList=Import-Csv C:\Users\RHyman\Documents\ExListTest.csv
FOREACH ($Person in $UserList)
{

```
Get-ADUser -Identity $UserList.UserPrincipalName
```